# Firebase sends Password Reset emails without necessary API key

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm currently building a Flutter app integrated with Firebase authentication. I'm using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to authenticate my users, which is functioning correctly.

However, I encountered an issue when attempting to reset passwords using FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail. While Firebase sends a password reset email to my inbox, clicking the link in the email results in an error message stating:

> The selected page mode is invalid.

Upon inspection, I noticed that the API key is missing from the link. Manually inserting the API key resolves the issue, allowing the link to function properly.so how do i make sure the apikey is not omitted with firebase sends the link:

[image: Code for reset Password]

the link with missing API KEY:https://skin-disease-detection-s-57573.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=N7p147fBJ12IrYDa_xhKSyhgfuTd9bOh7b1KKSvMqq4AAAGN0ikwvw&apiKey=&lang=en

[image: Error link]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

I've asking around, and as far as I understand this may be a quota issue in our back-end systems and engineering is working on a fix. There is nothing you can do about it, so I recommend [reaching out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to report the problem and so that they can keep you up to date on progress.

*I'm also trying to figure out why this isn't posted on the [Firebase status](https://status.firebase.google.com/) page and/or [Cloud status](https://status.cloud.google.com/) page.*